# animating sphere

Tags: flash

I want to create an animating sphere representing the earth but here is the catch i want the users to be able to spin it round in real time, any suggestions what tools will do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you download [Processing](http://processing.org/), start at [this learning resource](http://processing.org/learning/), and work your way through the 3D examples that come with Processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [PaperVision3D](http://blog.papervision3d.org/).  It has the built-in functionality to create a sphere.

Comment: If you're working with Flash, PaperVision3D is the way to go.